# How to write a PL SQL procedure to display all records from table Employee using cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, rdbms

This is my code so far .
This procedure  gets created with compilation errors!!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_information_for_all_Employees
    v_name  Employee.NAME%TYPE;
    v_id  Employee.ID%TYPE;
    v_dept  Employee.DEPARTMENT%TYPE;
    CURSOR employees IS SELECT NAME,ID,DEPARTMENT FROM Employee;
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN employees;
    LOOP
        FETCH employees into v_name,v_id,v_dept;
        dbms_output.put_line (' Employee ' || v_name);
        dbms_output.put_line( 'having ID' || v_id );
        dbms_output.put_line ('works in Department' || v_dept);
        EXIT WHEN employees%notfound;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE employees;
END get_information_for_all_Employees;
```

Can anybody please figure out whats wrong with it?
I have tried my best ,but cant figure it out!
Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you are new to PL/SQL then consider learning programming constructs first before directly jumping to cursors. You may start with Anonymous blocks and understand the mandatory and optional parts of a block, keywords, and a lot more before trying to do complex things.

Comment: For f;uture reference .. when you ask for help resolving an error message ("_created with compilation errors_"), it would be very helpful to include the actual error message.

Answer (score 3):

You have put the `AS` keyword in the wrong place.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_information_for_all_Employees
   AS
v_name  Employee.NAME%TYPE;
v_id  Employee.ID%TYPE;
v_dept  Employee.DEPARTMENT%TYPE;
CURSOR employees IS SELECT NAME,ID,DEPARTMENT FROM Employee;
BEGIN
    OPEN employees;
    LOOP
        FETCH employees into v_name,v_id,v_dept;
        dbms_output.put_line (' Employee ' || v_name);
        dbms_output.put_line( 'having ID' || v_id );
        dbms_output.put_line ('works in Department' || v_dept);
        EXIT WHEN employees%notfound;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE employees;
END get_information_for_all_Employees;
```

Or you can create is it like this using Cursor for loop

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_information_for_all_Employees
   AS
CURSOR employees IS SELECT NAME,ID,DEPARTMENT FROM Employee;
BEGIN
    FOR rec in employees
    LOOP
        
        dbms_output.put_line (' Employee ' || rec.NAME);
        dbms_output.put_line( 'having ID' || rec.ID );
        dbms_output.put_line ('works in Department' || rec.DEPARTMENT);
       
    END LOOP;
   
END get_information_for_all_Employees;
```

Comment: Agree with a suggestion about `for rec in cursor` from Aman and EdSteven, because it allows PL/SQL engine to use optimized fetch by 100 rows hiddenly.

Answer (score 2):

@Aman Singh Rajpoot spotted the actual error and offered an improved use of the cursor. I'd like to offer a better (in my opinion) improvement on the cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_information_for_all_Employees
   AS
BEGIN
    FOR rec in (SELECT NAME,ID,DEPARTMENT FROM Employee)
    LOOP

        dbms_output.put_line (' Employee ' || rec.NAME);
        dbms_output.put_line( 'having ID' || rec.ID );
        dbms_output.put_line ('works in Department' || rec.DEPARTMENT);
       
    END LOOP;
   
END get_information_for_all_Employees;
```

Comment: I am curious, is there any performance difference between my and your cursor for loop?

Comment: I've never tested it, but then I've never had reason.  I just find my version to be more concise.  If there _is_ a difference, I would expect it to be negligible in all but the most extreme cases.  Actually, I would expect the _compiled_ code to be identical.

Comment: I had a similar type of question in the Oracle dev gym but the result showed there is not much difference and there are better ways to do performance tuning. But if your cursor query is big then you may want to declare it separately.

Comment: _"if your cursor query is big "_   Define "big".    And once that is defined, on what grounds would one "may want to declare it separately"?   Performance?  If the definition of "big" is based on "lines of code",  then perhaps there comes a point where a programmer would prefer to have a separately declared cursor.  That would become a matter of personal choice/taste.  I started out 40 years ago as a cobol programmer, and no matter what language I'm writing, I've always try to consider the guy who would be maintaining my code after me.

Comment: If you don't mind I would like to ask you a question. What technology or programming language should I learn with PLSQL to make better use of it?

Comment: "What technology or programming language should I learn with PLSQL to make better use of it?"   Any of them. All of them. No education is ever wasted.  My college degree is in music, and even aspects of that helped at one time. I think the best is to learn assembler.  Get right down next to the machine language itself and you gain a much better understanding and appreciation of all of the layers piled on top of it.

Comment: An artist doesn’t discriminates between art. Thank you.